# How to enable URL routing in Node and Elm application (Heroku)?

Tags: node.js, heroku, elm

I have an elm application running on Heroku.

I didn't want to use a third party elm buildpack, so I compiled the elm files locally and pushed elm.js onto the Heroku server.

My application is using Node.js backend so I'm using this code in expresss to 
serve index.html:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client'));

  app.get('*', (res:any) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```

I can go to the heroku URL and everything works perfectly. If I click on the internal `/login` link, I'm redirected to the `login` page and my url changes to `ww.mywebsite.com/login`. **Internal routing is not my problem.**

**This is my problem:** Although internal routing works, if I were to manually write `www.mywebsite.com/login` in the navigation bar, instead of seeing the `login` page, I see `Internal Server Error`

How do I fix this? Would I need a heroku buildback to accomplish this?

Comment: Your route `*` should match all incoming requests and respond with the static file. Firstly, Internal Server Error indicates that it finds the route, since otherwise it should return 404 to your browser. So, this needs more information. Secondly, your route will always return the static file, meaning that you are not giving Elm app the information about browser's address. Unfortunately I don't know straight away how to fix the second issue. P.S. AFAIK Heroku is irrelevant in this case, since you should be able to reproduce the issue by running Node/Express on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kaskelotti from the comments pointed out, `Internal Server Error` was printing because the files were being found, but another error was happening once they were found. If the files had not been found I would have received a 404 error.

This was a syntax error in my express code that matched all requests with my static index.html file.

The code posted in my question is wrong, THIS is how it should look:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client'));

  app.get('*', (req , res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```

The difference is the argument to the callback function in `app.get`. Originally it was `(res)` instead of `(req, res)`, so the `res` variable was mistaken for an object of type `Request` and not `Response`, since it was the first argument.

Also as @kaskelotti pointed out, Heroku is irrelevant to this problem.